# How to Install MYSQL Preference Pane?

Tags: mysql, macos

Quick question.

I have been trying to make MySQL work to no luck. When I downloaded MySQL from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ (the latest version for Mac, 5.7.21), I followed all the instructions. When I go to System Preferences and click on the MySQL icon, it tells me:

*Preferences Error: Could not load MySQL Preference Pane*. Any solution to this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try [googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=MySQL+Preference+Pane&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS755US755&oq=MySQL+Preference+Pane&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.227j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)? Looks like you need to install the Preferences Pane.

Comment: I have installed it, but when I click on it, it says the following error.

Comment: Description formatted properly

Answer (score 7):

Same problem with MySQL Preference Pane after updating from 5.7.20 to 5.7.21.

The solution for me was to remove MySQL Preference Pane (https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-remove-preference-panes-from-mac-2260890) and install it again from the 5.7.20 DMG Archive (https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community).

Comment: thank you so much! This was the solution that worked

Comment: how would I only install the preference pane from 5.7.20?

Comment: When your are on "Installation Type" click the "Customize" button to select only "Preference Pane". Take a look at the doc: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/osx-installation-pkg.html

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Uninstall MySQL completely and install MySQL 5.6 instead worked fine for me.

Follow these instructions:
https://devmarketer.io/learn/do-not-install-mysql-macos-sierra-how-to-fix/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately a known bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=89140 - seems to have hit all latest mysql versions (5.6 / 5.7 / 8.0)